# Formula for calculation for total size of texured mesh of a home in gigabytes

Tags: textures, mesh

I'm trying to calculate the size in GB for textures + meshes for someone's home of size 1500 sq ft containing ([around 12K total objects](https://petapixel.com/2022/07/08/photographer-documents-all-12795-items-that-she-owns/)) for 3 LODs.

I understand this number can vary quite a bit depending on the size of the texture, etc. But I wasn't quite sure of all the variables required and also I'm not sure what is the anecdotal size used in AAA games for very detailed maps of that size at 3 LODs.

So the formula will look something like
size in GB for 1500 sqft home = 12K X (average size of texture X average size of mesh) X LOD factor

I'm not sure if average is a good, but hey, its a start.

Comment: There's no clear answer here. Can be as simple as 0 (using vertex colors) or procedural texture generation, to as much as you can imagine (over9000gb).

Comment: What are you trying to solve? It might be preferible to underestimate or overestimate depending what the estimation is for. Also, I remind you that poorly optimized meshes are poorly optimized, and optimizing them takes time. Are you considering how much time will put in modeling and texturing everything? On a similar note, we would ideally reuse. If we don't put effort in any of that, then yes, your approach is correct. Otherwise I expect it to be grow sub-linearly. Finally, aesthetics. Depending on the style you are going for, you might need heavier textures or more detailed models.

Comment: Looks like a XY Problem to me.

Comment: This is roughly backwards to the way game data is usually budgeted. Typically we'll set our target system spec including available video memory, then subdivide that number between our various game systems, then subdivide each division between the max assets we need to show/simulate at a time, and get a target texture size/vertex count per object (or per category of object, with "hero" objects getting a bigger slice of the budget than minor background details). Then we make or edit the meshes and textures and apply optimization tricks to fit that budget.